# Android: Generic way to mount a windows share via USB

Tags: android, windows, mount

I am looking for a *generic* way to mount windows shares via the USB cable (not WiFi). By generic, I mean a method that does not require device specific kernel modules.

If this is not achievable, I am open to other ideas but WiFi/internet connectivity is totally out of the question.

My development machine is sitting on a domain and the shares are likely to be on another machine, not necessarily local on my host machine.

Any thoughts or suggestions are greatly welcomed.

Many thanks,
P

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without kernel modules, because kernel modules are the thing that does the whole job. So your question is like "i am looking for the way to put that water into the glass, but without the glass part". So apps may offer SMB support, but that's because these apps include all the code to handle SMB inside. So if you want to mount samba share on filesystem level you need kernel module and sufficient permissions. Otherwise you just need to look for app that supports SMB and does what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am aware that kernel modules are required, but I am looking for either a solution to this (which seems highly unlikely) or an alternative. I simply require the ability to transfer files from my device to a windows share via USB.

Answer (score -1):

I'm definetly considering to use a chroot of some linux installation to implement a smb arm linux server on android, you can run all sorts of ARM linux tools inside an android machine trough chroot, once in linux there's not much you can't do, and the simplest distro available can pretty much install whatever you want. Of course, you can strip just the server binaries inside a package and run that just like an android app of some sort, or install the binaries in /system/bin and xbin in android and add some init script. Whatever rocks your boat.
BTW, my implementation involves a USB-ramdrive, i want my 2GB RAM MK809II android device to store a 1GB img file in a tmpfs ramdisk, mounted in a place accessible by all apps like /sdcard/ram/ram.img, where i can create a smb share to a windows machine, that connection will be made via USB, i'll use adb reverse to connect to the SMB share and redirect the server ports to my local tcp 7777 1137 1138 1139, my smb filesharing server has already been disabled, so these relevant ports are free to use in my pc, that's important because windows will only recognize servers running in the same ports. I'll access the smb share from windows and mount the img file in the share trough ImDisk to have my virtual 
 ramdrive under windows.
 I have a pc with only 1.5gb of ram, and sometimes this thing run out of memory, i want to have a readyboost drive that's lightning fast compared to a solid state usb drive, i want to have usb as a bottleneck in my transfer speed..... some time ago i saw a 50MB/s usb2.0 hdd then i wondered what would happen if i can bottleneck the fck out of usb2.0, that's completely inviable via it's original solid state bottlenecked drives, but ram in the other hand has almost no speed limit... so i got my little project, out of some need and mostly curiosity. I'm chasing for a way into store the pagefile in that ramdisk, though i think windows readyboost already stores virtual memory pages in the readyboost 
file.